# Maya LT / Cinema4D Rig to Blender?

Tags: rigging, export

Is there a way for us to export Maya LT or Cinema4D Rig to Blender?
Even if we need to redo the controls, it'd be a great start!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You always have the possibility to handle the I/O using FBX. FBX can save skeletal and skinning information. Constraints and controls would have to be rebuild. Also the bone orientations and rotation orders might be different and need to be adjusted manually, depending on the import and export settings. All in all if you manage to reduce the source file to just skinned mesh, you should be able to reuse at least some of the work you have already done.

Comment: Heya! Thanks for the reply. I've actually tried importing my skinned mesh in, and I did indeed see the bones all messed... How do I go about fixing that? Do I need to unbind the skin, and just fix up the skeleton manually? I was secretly hoping there would be like a magic script or plugin here :)

Comment: Well, I would suggest different methods depending on the amount of bones you have and the software you use. I cannot give you an universal answer for this as it really depends on how you export and import and what version of software you use. The FBX SDK has a lot of features but it is quite different how software packages use them. If you post a blend and the corresponding FBX I can take a look at it for you and give you advice.

Comment: Thanks for the offer! Was mostly exploring options, but looks like we're just gonna use Blender from the ground up instead of like a mixed workflow.